# Button requires double click to activate click event

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

This bug seems impossible to squash and it's followed me to two different projects now ( the first one I scrapt). below is the code:

```
   


    if(testIterator.hasNext()){

        layers.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.layer1, testIterator.next())
        basePicture.setImageDrawable(layers)
    }
    else{
        hairButton.isFocusable = false

        layers.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.layer1,test.first())
        basePicture.setImageDrawable(layers)
        testIterator = test.iterator()

    }

}
```

"layers" is a layer-list.xml in the drawable folder. With this iterator I am iterating through an array of drawables(?) called "test". The drawables inside "test" are replacing an individual drawable inside of my layer-list.xml.

the if statements function is to ( like stated prior) , iterate through a list of drawables(?) and replace the current with the next if the user clicks the button again. This should change the graphics on the screen as well when the button is clicked.

The else statements function is to go back to element [0] of the array list "test" once the button has been clicked all the way to the last function ( like a restart).

**The Problem:**
I have to click on the button twice for it to get off the element[0] and begin iterateing. It does NOT require a double tap afterwards, atleast not until it gets back to element[0]. I have researched this issue and some have said it has to do with " focus", but I have experimented with focusability extensively and I don't think thats the problem.

I don't think its the line that says:
"basePicture.setImageDrawable(layers)"
I don't think this is the problem because I (think) I need this like to update how the image looks on the screen, and when I comment this line out it makes no difference.

P.S.
when I do iterate it does not immediately show up on screen. I have to click the home button ( so the app disappears) and reopen it to see any change in what graphic is being shown. This is a new bug I have discovered so I haven't started really looking into it yet, but any ideas on what this is would be really helpful. Thank You!

Comment: Why not use an index property instead of the iterator? Hanging onto an iterator long term is not very robust.

Comment: @Tenfour04   Like a "for" loop with breaks that are attached to clicklistener?

Comment: I wasn't thinking of any loops. You wouldn't be able to do that without some convoluted coroutine implementation. Just hang onto the reference of the last index used. Increment it when using it, rolling it around when it gets to the size of the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you loop back to the start (in your `else` clause) you set the image to display the first layer, and then create a new iterator for the next loop.

But you're not actually taking the first element from the iterator, so on the next click, it calls `next()` - which produces the next item, i.e. the first one, which is the first layer. You end up displaying it again.

The simplest fix is just to call `next()` after you recreate the iterator, pop off that first element you don't need. A better way would be to move your displaying code into a common function:

```
fun showNextLayer() {
    layers.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.layer1, testIterator.next())
    basePicture.setImageDrawable(layers)
}

...

if (!testIterator.hasNext()) {
    hairButton.isFocusable = false
    testIterator = test.iterator()
}
showNextLayer()
```

You could also roll your own infinite iterator, so you don't need to check it or recreate it, and you can just call `next()` on every click

```
class LayerIterator : Iterator<Int> {
    private var current = -1

    override fun hasNext() = true

    override fun next(): Int {
        // increment the current index, wrapping back to zero
        current = (current + 1) % layers.size
        return layers[current]
    }
}
```

but because you're in Kotlin, you can just do an infinite sequence!

```
val iterator = generateSequence(0) { (it + 1) % layers.size }
    .map(layers::get)
    .iterator()
```

---

**edit** - your problem with stuff not showing up... I haven't used them personally, but I think you need to use a [`LevelListDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable), not a [`LayerDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable).

The latter is basically a collection that stacks a bunch of drawables into one combined visual element you can reference easily, I don't think it's made for switching which of those is on the top. But a `LevelListDrawable` is for assigning values to a set of drawables, and then you call `setLevel` on it to control which one is shown. (The example they give is for the battery icon and its different states.)

So you should just need to set that drawable on `basePicture` once, and then set the drawable's `level` to change what's displayed

Comment: I tried out Levellist and  but I had an issue.  I am trying to change layers of drawables to different images, kind of like when you customize a character you can change its hair style ( you can change nose shape too) . I tryed to created a single layer drawable with each item being a levellist drawable. when I set my main images drawable to layerlist I see no changes. Also I tried the infinite sequence but it wouldn't let me get my levellist size . Do you think I should try to use Canvas instead of the layer list idea. @cactustictacs

Comment: Oh so you actually are drawing a stack of drawables, not just one at a time? Ok, I guess you need a ``LayerDrawable`` in that case, so your original code should be fine, except you shouldn't need to set it on ``basePicture`` repeatedly - you set the layer list as its drawable once, then you can just mess with the layer list itself. It should just work (I haven't used these but still) - you could try calling ``invalidate()`` on the ``ImageView`` but it should be automatic. Don't bother with ``Canvas``es unless you need to. And for the sequences you want the length/size of ``test``, your source